# Dynamic sql query with stored procedure and table variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I want to call a stored procedure dynamically as my names of the procedures are stored somewhere, also I need to store the result of that procedure into a table variable. Hence I had to write following sql code,

In following code
    @tblEmailIds is the table variable which I want to store the result of SP in
    @tempEmailSource is the name of the procedure
    @tempRecipientsIdsCSV is the first argument that my SP is accepting
    @ObjectMasterId is the second argument that SP is accepting (optional)

```
DECLARE @tempTypeName NVARCHAR(100), 
            @tempTypeId INT,
            @tempEmailSource NVARCHAR(100),
            @tempRecipientsIdsCSV NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @tempIsObjectSpecific BIT,
            @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO @tblEmailIds '
SELECT TOP 1 @tempTypeName = NAME, 
@tempTypeId = Id,         
@tempEmailSource = EmailListSourceName 
FROM @tbleRecipientsTypes WHERE IsEmailIdsFetched = 0

    SELECT @tempRecipientsIdsCSV = SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT ',' + CAST(RT.EmailRecipientId AS NVARCHAR(50))
    FROM @tbleRecipientsTypes RT WHERE RT.Id = @tempTypeId
    ORDER BY RT.EmailRecipientId
    FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000)

    SELECT @tempRecipientsIdsCSV


    SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'EXEC ' + @tempEmailSource +' ' +''''  +    @tempRecipientsIdsCSV +''''
    IF (@tempIsObjectSpecific = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' ' + @ObjectMasterId
    END

    PRINT @SQLQUERY

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL 
    @SqlQuery,'@IdsCSV NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,  
    @ObjectMasterId INT = NULL OUTPUT', @tblEmailIds
```

I am getting the following error

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 6 Procedure
>   expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here.

1. As the error message clearly states, the parameter list needs to be `NVARCHAR` so just prefix that string literal with an `N` (as also stated in @VR46's answer).
2. Table variables do not work the way that you are trying to use them. First, you do not ever declare `@tblEmailIds`, but even if you did, the scope of a table variable is local, and they cannot be used as `OUTPUT` parameters. Instead, you need to create a local temporary table (i.e. `#tblEmailIds`) and do `INSERT INTO #tblEmailIds`.
3. You reference another table variable, `@tbleRecipientsTypes`, that has not been declare or populated.
4. You do declare `@tempIsObjectSpecific` but never set it so it will always be `NULL`.
5. Why is `@IdsCSV` (in the `sp_executesql` call parameter list) declared as `OUTPUT`? Not only are you not passing in `@tempRecipientsIdsCSV` (to be `@IdsCSV` in the dynamic SQL), it isn't even necessary to be a parameter since you are directly concatenating the value of `@tempRecipientsIdsCSV` into the Dynamic SQL, and there is no `@tempRecipientsIdsCSV` variable in the Dynamic SQL to begin with. So remove `@IdsCSV NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,` from the parameter list.
6. You say that "@tempRecipientsIdsCSV is the first argument that my SP is accepting", but then you declare it in the code, which should result in an error.
7. What datatype is `@ObjectMasterId`? You say that it is passed into the proc and I see that it is concatenated into the Dynamic SQL, so it needs to either be a string type (i.e. not `INT` like is shown in the `sp_executesql` parameter list) or it needs to be in a `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @ObjectMasterId`.
8. If `@ObjectMasterId` is being passed in, then why is it declared as `OUTPUT` in the `sp_executesql` parameter list? But the better question is probably: why are you even passing it into `sp_executesql` anyway since you directly concatenate it into the Dynamic SQL? There is no `@ObjectMasterId` variable being used in the Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks,  to summarize these are the changes I made, put N'', removed OUTPUT, and made @tblEmailIds as #tblEmailIds ... It worked

Comment: @RoshanBirwatkar You're welcome. I'm glad it worked. However, as I said, you can get rid of the parameter list and parameters entirely since you are not even using them. You can get away with just the `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SqlQuery;` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix `N` to the `@params` of `SP_EXECUTESQL`.

Also you need to store the result of `OUTPUT` parameter

```
Declare  @IdsCSV NVARCHAR(MAX),@ObjectMasterId INT = NULL

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL 
    @SqlQuery,
    N'@IdsCSV NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,@ObjectMasterId INT = NULL OUTPUT',
    @IdsCSV = @IdsCSV OUTPUT,
    @ObjectMasterId = @ObjectMasterId OUTPUT
```

Comment: You are correct that the param list needs to be prefixed with an `N`, but storing the result of the OUTPUT parameter isn't going to help because not only does it seem to not be an OUTPUT param, it isn't a parameter in the first place since it isn't used. In fact, either of those parameters are being used.